# How to use RegExp to check if string have at least two upper case letters but not one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a task to check a string value using RegExp **(I MUST USE REGEXP, so pls don't post solutions without regexp)** if it contains at least two upper case letters, at least two lower case letters and at least one number [0-9]. **EDIT** plus string length must be in between 5 and 15 characters (both 5 and 15 included).

I have this pattern: `/[A-Z].{2,}[a-z].{2,}[0-9].+/i`

But it doesn't work perfectly because it doesn't cover cases like if letters and numbers are not consecutive, one after another. Example:

`"nN1nN"` - will not pass the check

`"nnN1N"` -  -||- etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you check each condition separately in if else

Comment: I think `/^(?=.*[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z])\D*\d/` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi Wiktor, this pattern is working great, but I forgot to mention that I need to check for length to be between 5 and 15 characters (both included). Plus, can you give a bit of explanation of your pattern and can you modify your solution and paste it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: See [here](https://regex101.com/r/aLQpqs/1). All expalantions are on the right.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks